# Monitor Network folder for files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to run this query in powershell, but when I run it with the current `$MonitorFolder` as `\\\vavm\CINICO\Incoming` my query does not work when adding a file to the folder.  If I change the variable of `$MonitorFolder` to `C:\Users\RickG\Desktop\Test Reports`, my code works fine when adding the file to the folder. So how do I monitor the `\\vavm\CINICO\Incoming` path for when files are added to folder.

Here is a snippet of my first part of code that checks the folder:

```
$MonitorFolder = "\\vavm\CINICO\Incoming"
$MonitorStopFile = "monitor.die"
$smtpServer = "mail.test.org"
$smtpFrom = "SYSTEMFUNCTION@test.org" 
$smtpTo = "test@test.org"


$SourceID = "MonitorFiles"

$smtpSubject = "New file arrived in $($MonitorFolder)" 
$Query = @"
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10
WHERE targetInstance ISA 'Cim_DirectoryContainsFile'
AND targetInstance.GroupComponent = 'Win32_Directory.Name="$($MonitorFolder.Replace("\", "\\\\"))"'
"@
```

SOLUTION:

```
$MonitorFolder = "\\vavm\CINICO\incoming"
$MonitorStopFile = "monitor.die"

$smtpServer = "mail.test.org"
$smtpFrom = "SYSTEMFUNCTION@test.org" 
$smtpTo = "test@test.org"
$smtpSubject = "New file arrived in $($MonitorFolder)" 
$SourceID = "MonitorFiles"
$IncomingFiles = Get-ChildItem $MonitorFolder

$smtp = New-Object -TypeName "Net.Mail.SmtpClient" -ArgumentList $smtpServer

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $MonitorFolder
#Files only. Default is files + directory
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'

$newFileSubscription = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier NewFileCreated -Action { 
Write-Host "New file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)"

$smtpBody += "`n[$(Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss)]`tNew file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)"

if($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name -eq $MonitorStopFile) {
    Write-Host "Monitoring stopped"
    #Stop monitoring
    Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $newFileSubscription.Id
    #Dispose FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Dispose()
}
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom, $smtpTo, $smtpSubject, $smtpBody)      
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'does not work'? do you get an error?

Comment: The sample is incomplete. You never register the WMI-eventsubscriber

Comment: I do register the wmi event in the full code, thus is just a snippet

Comment: @ anthony stringer no error displays but the file descriptions are not emailed to me, if I change the path to a local folder the code works fine and sends the email with the file descriptions...let me know if you would like full code

Comment: A sample should be Minimal, complete and verifiable (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  so we can reproduce it. And why would you include all the smtp-info etc. if you're not even using them in the sample. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm 99% sure `__InstanceCreationEvent` doesn't support remote shares. WMI-events are trigged by your computer even if you don't have anything subscribing to it. Your computer can't monitor ever fileshare on the network.

You should try [`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to monitor remote shares. Ex.

```
$MonitorFolder = "\\vavm\CINICO\Incoming"
$MonitorStopFile = "monitor.die"

$smtpServer = "mail.test.org"
$smtpFrom = "SYSTEMFUNCTION@test.org" 
$smtpTo = "test@test.org"
$smtpSubject = "New file arrived in $($MonitorFolder)" 
$SourceID = "MonitorFiles"

$smtp = New-Object -TypeName "Net.Mail.SmtpClient" -ArgumentList $smtpServer

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $MonitorFolder
#Files only. Default is files + directory
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'

#Using a thread-safe collection (in global scope so Action-block can reach it) to store the log just to be safe.
$global:newFiles = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))

$newFileSubscription = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier NewFileCreated -Action {   
    Write-Host "New file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)"
    $global:newFiles.Add("[$(Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss)]`tNew file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)")

    if($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name -eq $MonitorStopFile) {
        Write-Host "Monitoring stopped"
        #Stop monitoring
        Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $newFileSubscription.Id
        #Dispose FileSystemWatcher
        $watcher.Dispose()
    }
}

while ($watcher.EnableRaisingEvents -or $global:newFiles.Count -gt 0) {   

    #Sleep
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

    if($global:newFiles.Count -gt 0) {
        #Convert list of strings to single string (multiline)
        $smtpbody = $global:newFiles | Out-String

        $smtp.Send($smtpFrom, $smtpTo, $smtpSubject, $smtpBody) 

        #Mail sent, Empty array
        $global:newFiles.Clear()
    }

}
```

Updated the sample above with a thread-safe global arraylist to store the "newfiles"-log in and a while-loop to create a mail ever minute if there are new items in the log.

Comment: Not sure how to use the system file watcher with my code and where to put it , i am a newbie to powershell, any help with a sample including my code would be appreciated.....Just seen the code you provided, I will try when I get home..

Comment: I've updated with a sample. A filesystemwatcher would work in the same way as an wmi-event. You set up monitoring and you include an action to be executed on the event. Nothing different. See sample

Comment: Ok I got this working with sending an email, but when I drop three files in folder it sends 3 emails, I only want it to send one email if multiple files were dragged and dropped into folder, I have edited my question with the working code in Solution:

Comment: Then add the new items to an array (in the event-action) and run a while-loop that sends an Email every minute if one or more files were created.

Comment: With my above solution it still sends 3 emails, The third being the correct email. If i move this line `$smtp.Send($smtpFrom, $smtpTo, $smtpSubject, $smtpBody) ` out of the action event it sends one e-mail but no body in the email

Comment: You're not using a while-loop. You're sending the mail on every call to the action-method which means it is sent every time a file is created (ex. 3 times). See updated sample.

Comment: I get this error now `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\RickG\Desktop\Test Reports\Untitled1.ps1:39 char:19
+         $smtp.Send <<<< ($smtpFrom, $smtpTo, $smtpSubject, $smtpBody) 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Send:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

Comment: yes, because the sample didn't include your smtp-initialization. that line was supposed to be commented out so you would see where to use it. :-) Fixing it now.

Comment: Oh wow lol, my mistake  I didn't even notice, thank you for all your help, I am a newbie to powershell, I had to remove the Outstring included in the $smtpbody and changed this `$global:newFiles.Add("`n[$(Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss)]`tNew file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)")`, and everything works just like I want now. Now if I can just get it to scan multiple directories at once

Comment: Glad I could help :-) I would make `$monitorfolder` a parameter and run multiple instances of the script with different folder paths. If the folders have a common parent, you can make the FileSystemWatcher monitor the root and enable recursive search (it's a property). Or you could make multiple watcher-objects that use the same Action-Block  etc.

Comment: Yes they are all the same pattern could i just use a wildcard like `\\vavm\*\incoming`

Comment: No, only recursive search is supported for a watcher (ex `\\vavm\incoming\*`). AFAIK You would need to use multiple watchers. You could ex. create one watcher per folder by using a foreach-loop on the output from `get-childitem` (or a list of paths). Good luck.